# How to copy a dict and modify it in one line of code

Tags: coding-style, python

Very often I need to create dicts that differ one from another by an item or two. Here is what I usually do:

```
setup1 = {'param1': val1, 
            'param2': val2,
            'param3': val3,
            'param4': val4,
            'paramN': valN}

setup2 = copy.deepcopy(dict(setup1))
setup2.update({'param1': val10, 
                   'param2': val20})
```

The fact that there is a point in the program at which `setup2` is an identical copy of `setup1` makes me nervous, as I'm afraid that at some point of the program life the two lines might get separated, which is a slippery slope towards too many bugs.

Ideally I would like to be able to complete this action in a single line of code (something like this):

```
setup2 = dict(setup1).merge({'param1': val10, 
                        'param2': val20})
```

Of course, I can use semicolon to squeeze two commands into  one physical line, but this looks pretty ugly to me. Are there other options?

Comment: `setup2 = dict(setup1)` is a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

Comment: `setup2 = dict(setup1)` is **not** a deep copy. Also, there is this thing called function, just write one.

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The simplest way in my opinion is something like this:

```
new_dict = {**old_dict, 'changed_val': value, **other_new_vals_as_dict}
```

Comment: Note that this only works from Python 3.5+, see https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/

Comment: Watch out: In the case where `old_dict` contains nested dictionaries, I think they will not be copied, but referenced in the `new_dict`. Later mutation of nested entries in `new_dict` will hence also modify `old_dict`'s nested entries.

Comment: small modification: `new_dict = {**copy.deepcopy(old_dict), 'changed_val': value, **other_new_vals_as_dict}`

Answer (score 55):

You could use keyword arguments in the dictionary constructor for your updates

```
new = dict(old, a=1, b=2, c=3)

# You can also unpack your modifications
new = dict(old, **mods)
```

This is equivalent to:

```
new = old.copy()
new.update({"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3})
```

[Source](https://www.ibisc.univ-evry.fr/%7Efpommereau/blog/2009-05-12-copy-a-python-dict-with-updates.html)

#### Notes

- `dict.copy()` creates a **shallow** copy.
- All keys **need to be strings** since they are passed as keyword arguments.

Comment: Which means that you can do `new = dict(old, **mods)` very conveniently.

Answer (score 20):

#### Solution

Build a function for that.

Your intention would be clearer when you use it in the code, and you can handle complicated decisions (e.g., deep versus shallow copy) in a single place.

```
def copy_dict(source_dict, diffs):
    """Returns a copy of source_dict, updated with the new key-value
       pairs in diffs."""
    result=dict(source_dict) # Shallow copy, see addendum below
    result.update(diffs)
    return result
```

And now the copy is atomic, assuming no threads involved:

```
setup2=copy_dict(setup1, {'param1': val10, 'param2': val20})
```

#### Addendum - deep copy

For primitives (integers and strings), there is no need for deep copy:

```
>>> d1={1:'s', 2:'g', 3:'c'}
>>> d2=dict(d1)
>>> d1[1]='a'
>>> d1
{1: 'a', 2: 'g', 3: 'c'}
>>> d2
{1: 's', 2: 'g', 3: 'c'}
```

If you need a deep copy, use the [`copy`](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module:

```
result=copy.deepcopy(source_dict) # Deep copy
```

instead of:

```
result=dict(setup1)               # Shallow copy
```

Make sure all the objects in your dictionary supports deep copy (any object that can be [`pickled`](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html#module-pickle) should do).

Comment: `And now the copy is atomic, assuming no threads involved` What do you mean by that?

Comment: The author means that it is "atomic from a code-perspective" (by which I assume they mean, it takes only a singe line of code).  They say it isn't safe for threads, but since it's a copy operation, the only source of thread unsafety would be if another thread modified either `source_dict` or  `diffs` while another thread was trying to copy them.  If both of `source_dict` and `diffs` are not modified, then it should be thread-safe as well.  I could be missing another source of thread-unsafety of course: anyone see any?

Answer (score 19):

```
setup2 = dict(setup1.items() + {'param1': val10, 'param2': val20}.items())
```

This way if new keys do not exist in `setup1` they get added, otherwise they replace the old key/value pairs.

Comment: Also nice :)  You can also directly use a list of pairs instead of `{...}.items()`.

Comment: Is this bound to a specific Python version? In 3.4, this returns me a `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict_items' and 'dict_items'`.

Comment: Yep, this is Python 2

Answer (score 13):

```
setup2 = dict((k, {'param1': val10, 'param2': val20}.get(k, v))
              for k, v in setup1.iteritems())
```

This only works if all keys of the update dictionary are already contained in `setup1`.

If all your keys are strings, you can also do

```
setup2 = dict(setup1, param1=val10, param2=val20)
```

Comment: This would not work if `'param1'` key does not exist in `setup1`, hence it won't be present in setup2 as well.

Answer (score 7):

From Python 3.9, you can use the pipe command (e.g. `first_dic | second_dic`) for merging dictionary; it can also be used for returning a new updated dictionary by passing the original dictionary first, and the update as a second dictionary:

```py
setup2 = setup1 | {'param1': val10, 'param2': val20}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just need to create a new dict with items from more than one dict, you can use:

```
dict(a.items() + b.items())
```

If both "a" and "b" have some same key, the result will have the value from b.
If you're using Python 3, the concatenation won't work, but you can do the same by freezing the generators to lists, or by using the itertools.chain function.

Comment: Or just wrapping each in a call to `list` or `tuple`.

Answer (score 2):

This is an extension to the nice answer posted by Adam Matan:

```py
def copy_dict(d, diffs={}, **kwargs):
    res = dict(d)
    res.update(diffs)
    res.update(kwargs)
    return res
```

The only difference is the addition of kwargs.
Now one can write

```py
setup2 = copy_dict(setup1, {'param1': val10, 'param2': val20})
```

or

```py
setup2 = copy_dict(setup1, param1=val10, param2=val20)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own class using `UserDict` wrapper, and simply add `dict`s like

```
# setup1 is of Dict type (see below)
setup2 = setup1 + {'param1': val10}
```

All you have to do is

- Define a new class using `UserDict` as base class
- Implement `__add__` method for it.

---

*Something like :*

```
class Dict(dict):
    def __add__(self, _dict):
        if isinstance(_dict, dict):
            tmpdict = Dict(self)
            tmpdict.update(_dict)
            return tmpdict

        else:
            raise TypeError

    def __radd__(self, _dict):
         return Dict.__add__(self, _dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like this line (after `from itertools import chain`):

```py
d3 = dict(chain(d1.items(), d2.items()))
```

(Thanks for juanpa.arrivillaga for the improvement!)

Comment: `{k: v for k,v in whatever}` -> `dict(whatever)`

Answer (score 0):

Some good answers above. I came here because I had the same issue.  Thought the function solution was the most elegant since the question mentioned "often"

```
def variant(common, diffs):
"""Create a new dict as a variant of an old one
"""
temp = common.copy()
temp.update(diffs)
return temp
```

to call it you simply use:

```
PTX130 = variant(PTX100, {'PA_r': 0.25, 'TX_CAP': 4.2E-10})
```

which for me says that the PTX130 is a variant of the PTX100 with different PA resistance and TX capacitance.