# slightly modify a copied dict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dict of the following format:

```
d = {'K1': [1, 2, 3], 'K2': [4, 5, 6], 'K3': [7, 8, 9]}
```

And I want to have N modified copies of this dict where the n:th dict ONLY has the n:th element of the list as value.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551672/how-to-copy-a-dict-and-modify-it-in-one-line-of-code) useful and powerful syntax on stackoverflow:

```
new_dict = {**old_dict, 'changed_val': value, **other_new_vals_as_dict}
```

The output should look like this (a list with N dicts), where the nth dict looks like this:

nth_dict = {"K1": vn}

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Could you be more specific about the input an the expected output?

Comment: "Can I use this?" <- Did you try?

Comment: The question is not clear. `Can I use this` We don't know. Why don't you give it a try and then post what you have tried and if you are still facing some issue

Comment: I've updated your question with an **actual** dictionary. Can you please show us **precisely** what you want for the 1st, 2nd and 3rd dictionaries in your list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you've linked to will not work.
If you take a few seconds to try it, you'll find that the syntax is only for modifying the keys in a dictionary - you can add keys or overwrite keys.
What you want to do is modify the key values in each dictionary.
There are a couple of ways you can do this, demonstrated on this simple example dictionary:

```
>>> d = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4, 5, 6]}
>>> d
{'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6]}
```

The most straightforward is using a list comprehension for each index, combined with a dictionary comprehension to recreate the dict each time.
If you aren't familiar with list comprehensions google it, they're an important part of python.

```
>>> [{k:l[i] for k, l in d.items()} for i in range(3)]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 4}, {'a': 2, 'b': 5}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6}]
```

You can also use a combination of zip with tuple unpacking

```
>>> [dict(zip(d.keys(), v)) for v in zip(*d.values())]
[{'a': 1, 'b': 4}, {'a': 2, 'b': 5}, {'a': 3, 'b': 6}]
```

Comment: thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list-comprehension with a nested dictionary-comprehension:

```
>>> d = {"K1": ["v1","v2","v3"], "K2": ["w1","w2","w3"]}
>>> [{k: v[i] for k, v in d.items()} for i in range(min(map(len, d.values())))]
[{'K1': 'v1', 'K2': 'w1'},
 {'K1': 'v2', 'K2': 'w2'},
 {'K1': 'v3', 'K2': 'w3'}]
```

If the values should still be lists, wrap them into `[...]`:

```
>>> [{k: [v[i]] for k, v in d.items()} for i in range(min(map(len, d.values())))]
[{'K1': ['v1'], 'K2': ['w1']},
 {'K1': ['v2'], 'K2': ['w2']},
 {'K1': ['v3'], 'K2': ['w3']}]
```

Of course, if you know the number of elements in the lists, you can  replace `min(map(len, d.values()))` with just that number.